# oauth flow in github api v3 not working

Tags: python, api, oauth, github

So this should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to find my fail point.  Hopefully someone else can point it out to me.

First I go to `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=gist` and this returns a code to me. Then I do this:

```
import requests, json

client_id = XXXX
client_secret = XXXX
code = XXXX

r = requests.post(
    'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', 
    data=json.dumps({
        'client_id':client_id, 
        'client_secret':client_secret,
        'code':code
    })
r.content  # this gives me a 404 header
```

When I go to my test user it shows me as authorized and my app shows as having one user, but I don't have a access token.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I was right this was a really simple problem, but I'll leave this here incase others run into the same error.

When in doubt manually define your header.  So you need:

```
header = {'content-type':'application/json'}
```

And then pass in the header:

```
r = requests.post(
    'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', 
    data=json.dumps({
        'client_id':client_id, 
        'client_secret':client_secret,
        'code':code
    }),
    headers=header
)
```

For me this solved the problem.